# Type.GetType fails when invoked as method group but not in lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, lambda

The following example shows Type.GetType failing in a specific scenario.

GetType succeeds when I provide it the class name string (including namespace) in a lambda expression, but fails when I specify the call to GetType as a method group.

Fails:

```
collectionOfClassNames.Select(GetType)
```

Succeeds:

```
collectionOfClassNames.Select(s => GetType(s))
```

Both methods succeed when the class path includes the assembly name. I suspect it's something to do with the current context/scope given the IL generated for the above. I can see the differences in the IL but I still can't explain the exact cause.

The below is a runnable example that demonstrates the problem.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace GetTypeTest
{
    public class FindMe{}

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var assemblyName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;
            var className = "GetTypeTest.FindMe";
            var classAndAssembly = string.Format("{0}, {1}", className, assemblyName);

            // 1) GetType succeeds when input is "class, assembly", using method group
            var result = new[] { classAndAssembly }.Select(Type.GetType).ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine("1) Method group & class+assembly: {0}", result.First());

            // 2) GetType fails when input is just the class name, using method group
            var result2 = new[] { className }.Select(Type.GetType).ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine("2) Method group & class name only: {0}", result2.First());

            // 3) Identical to (2) except using lamba expression - this succeeds...
            var result3 = new[] { className }.Select(s => Type.GetType(s)).ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine("3) Lambda expression & class name only: {0}", result3.First());

            // 4) Method group and core type class name
            var result4 = new[] { "System.String" }.Select(Type.GetType).ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine("4) Method group for System.String: {0}", result4.First());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to know why #2 fails but #3 succeeds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Am not 100% sure,  I may be wrong.</strike>. I'll propose what I've examined.

Version 2 gets compiled into a func delegate like this `new Func<string, Type>(Type.GetType)`

Version 3 gets compiled into a compiler generated method in your same class something like this

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private static Type <Main>b__0(string s)
{
    Type type;
    type = Type.GetType(s);
Label_0009:
    return type;
}
```

and to a func `new Func<string, Type>(Program.<Main>b__0)`

So, While executing your enumerator *Version2* is just a `func` which will be invoked my `WhereSelectArrayIterator<TSource, TResult>` private class **lives in System.Core.dll**

Where as *Version3* **lives in your assembly**.

Coming to the point. If `Type.GetType` is invoked with partial names(without fully qualified name) It doesn't knows which assembly the type resides, It gets the calling `assembly` and assumes the type lives there.

Hence *Version3* lives in your assembly `Type.GetType` figured out your type's assembly and scans the assembly fully returns the correct type.

But this is not the case in *Version2*. You're not actually invoking the `Type.GetType` there. It is being invoked by `WhereSelectArrayIterator... class` which is in `System.Core.dll`. So this assumes your type lives in `System.Core.dll` and `Type.GetType` fails to find out your type.

---

**Edit:**
Following snippet proves above statements were correct

We fake a class in our assembly and name it `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` to see the behavior.

```
namespace GetTypeTest
{
    public class FindMe { }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var assemblyName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;
            var className = "System.Linq.Expressions.Expression";//"GetTypeTest.FindMe";
            var classAndAssembly = string.Format("{0}, {1}", className, assemblyName);

            // 1) GetType succeeds when input is "class, assembly", using method group
            var result = new[] { classAndAssembly }.Select(Type.GetType).ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine("1) Method group & class+assembly: {0}, {1}", result.First(), result.First().Assembly);//your assembly

            // 2) GetType fails when input is just the class name, using method group
            var result2 = new[] { className }.Select(Type.GetType).ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine("2) Method group & class name only: {0}, {1}", result2.First(), result2.First().Assembly);//System.Core assembly

            // 3) Identical to (2) except using lamba expression - this succeeds...
            var result3 = new[] { className }.Select(s => Type.GetType(s)).ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine("3) Lambda expression & class name only: {0}, {1}", result3.First(), result3.First().Assembly);//your assembly

            // 4) Method group and core type class name
            var result4 = new[] { "System.String" }.Select(Type.GetType).ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine("4) Method group for System.String: {0}, {1}", result4.First(), result4.First().Assembly);//mscorlib assembly

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

namespace System.Linq.Expressions
{
    public class Expression
    {

    }
}
```

Outputs

```
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression [your assembly]
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression [System.Core assembly] since WhereSelectArrayIterator.. belongs to System.Core assembly
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression [your assembly] since compiler generated method belongs to your assembly
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression [mscorlib assembly]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This sounds correct. It is often easier to use [`Assembly.GetType(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb.aspx) instead. For instance with `var assem = typeof(Program).Assembly;`, it is no problem to use `stringColl.Select(assem.GetType)`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yup, You're correct else we need to use fully qualified name. BTW my statements were correct. Updated my answer with proof :)

Comment: Using the calling assembly as input to a method is hideous API design on the part of the BCL.

Comment: @usr I agree, but I think there is no other way to do that(finding Type without assembly name). Worst idea would be scan all loaded assemblies, So they just check calling assemby is my guess.